# django tastypie REST query filtering based on authorised user

Tags: python, django, rest, tastypie

I'm looking to make changes to django web app that provides a REST interface via tastypie. The app is available at:
https://github.com/OWASP/django-DefectDojo/

Within the app, *Users* have *Products* that they are authorised to view and *Endpoints* belonging to the *Products*.

The models are defined at:
https://github.com/OWASP/django-DefectDojo/blob/master/dojo/models.py#L177
https://github.com/OWASP/django-DefectDojo/blob/master/dojo/models.py#L417

I have added EndpointResource to `dojo/api.py`:

```
class EndpointResource(BaseModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = Endpoint.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'endpoints'
        fields = ['product', 'protocol', 'host', 'path', 'query', 'fragment']

        list_allowed_methods = ['get']
        detail_allowed_methods = ['get']
        include_resource_uri = True
        filtering = {
            'product': ALL,
            'protocol': ALL,
            'host': ALL,
        }
        authorization = DjangoAuthorization()
        authentication = DojoApiKeyAuthentication()
        serializer = Serializer(formats=['json'])
```

class Product contains:
`authorized_users = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True)`
class Endpoint contains:
`product = models.ForeignKey(Product, null=True, blank=True, )`

Currently, Users can authenticate to `/api/v1/endpoints/` and they will see all Endpoints.

```
curl -v --header 'Authorization: ApiKey sue:5b632d76ef1a38b8375383e3498d063515b356d4' http://example.com/api/v1/endpoints/
```

However, the desired behaviour is that Users should only be able to access Products they are authorised for, along with related entities to these products.

From within a python session I can do:

```
>>> from dojo.models import User, Product, Endpoint
>>> User.objects.get(username='sue').product_set.all().get().endpoint_set.all()
[<Endpoint: goliath.sue.local>, <Endpoint: goliath.suelimited.co>, <Endpoint: 192.168.10.11>]
```

These objects, associated with 'sue' are the ones that I want returned by the API.
What would be the best way to get this going with tastypie?
Any help much appreciated, let me know if I need to post up further info.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to perhaps to  subclass `DjangoAuthorization`. See more in the docs [here](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.io/en/latest/authorization.html).

```
from tastypie.authorization import DjangoAuthorization

from tastypie.exceptions import Unauthorized


class UserEndpointAuthorization(DjangoAuthorization):

    def read_list(self, object_list, bundle):
        # Do your filter here against the queryset to limit it
        # to only the endpoints they can see.
        return object_list.filter(....)
```

Comment: Thanks jaywhy13, the current DjangoAuthorization is working OK so would rather leave. I've added a working answer below but interested to see if it's proper practice.

Answer (score 0):

Using the code at the link
https://github.com/OWASP/django-DefectDojo/blob/master/dojo/finding/views.py#L68
as a guide, the following method was added to class EndpointResource:

```
def get_object_list(self, request):
    return super(EndpointResource, self).get_object_list(request).filter(product__authorized_users__in=[request.user])
```

It performs as I described but interested to get feedback to see if it's proper practice.

Comment: That works well too. According to the write up [here](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.io/en/latest/resources.html#flow-through-the-request-response-cycle), all the requests that come in have to pass through ``get_object_list``, not to be confused with ``get_list`` which is the API call to list objects. The ``Authorization`` approach (I meant to subclass ``DjangoAuthorization``) works better if you want to reuse the class across several resources.

Comment: Also, I guess part of it is design choice as well. Using the ``Authorization`` approach allows you to act differently depending on the request type (list vs detail for example). Using the filtering approach would mean the client would get a 404 trying to access an endpoint they have no permissions for, as opposed to raising an ``Unauthorized`` in a ``read_detail`` method. Depends on which you prefer. The ``Authorization`` classes were really designed to determine who can access what, so that was my go to suggestion. All the best!

Comment: I'm leaning towards the generic 404 so that the resources cannot be enumerated for naughty purposes. Thanks again!